# Is there a way to verify that a method on Spring Controller was called using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

This is my Mockito Test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Controller_Test {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeController employeeController;

    @Mock
    private InputValidationService inputValidationService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(restController).build();

    }

    @Test
    public void testGetEmployeeDetails() {

        EmployeeController spy = Mockito.spy(employeeController);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/employee/details/9816")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

    // Have some basic asserts here on the result that are working fine


    }


    }
```

Now my question is, Is there a way to assert that the method I expected to be called in my controller was actually invoked.

I know it was, but how do I assert it with unit test

For e.g. 
This is my RequestMapping in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/details/{id}", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody   
    public EmployeeDetails getEmployeeDetailsById(@PathVariable String employeeID) {

    //Some business logic

    }
```

Now I would like to make some assertion like:

```
Mockito.verify(spy, times(1)).getEmployeeDetailsById();
```

So basically I would like to assert that the  method I expected to get called was the one that got called. I know this can be done on the Mock Service object that I have i.e. inputValidationService but would like something similar for the controller as well.

Please let me know if there are any additional details that you would like me to post.

Comment: That's not how MockMvc is meant to be used. You should be verifying (matching) on the response.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I get it and I have the assert on the response as well. But I have multiple mappings that return the same result. And like I said I have other asserts to see that the method I expect to be called is getting called but I wanted to know if there is a way I can assert the correct mapping was called directly by Mockito. I am not concerned about how MockMvc is supposed to be used, this is like a technially possible or not question.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe late, but I found org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.HandlerResultMatchers which can verify the proper controller and method are being called.  For example:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.handler;

    mockMvc
        .perform(get("/employee/details/9816"))
        .andExpect(handler().handlerType(EmployeeController.class))
        .andExpect(handler().methodName("getEmployeeDetailsById"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @MockBean.This will use Mockito beans for which you will be able to use standart Mockito functions like "verify".

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans